# Deleting first row in R studio error incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: rstudio

I removed the header in my data but I am having troubles removing the first row. Basically I want to turn 
1
2
3
4
5

into

2
3
4
5

I keep getting this error. I am using a number because it is the title of my gage.

> "11481000" = "11481000"[-1,]
>   Error in "11481000"[-1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
>   "11481000"[-1,]
>   Error in "11481000"[-1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
>   View(`11481000`)
>   "11481000" <- "11481000" [-c(1), ]
>   Error in "11481000"[-c(1), ] : incorrect number of dimensions

TIA

Comment: could you please provide the r script that you used to have that error?

Comment: I figured it out thank you!!!  b <- a[2:nrow(a), ]